# C# Linq - Create a dynamic select query based on user input

Tags: c#, sql, linq, dynamic

**Use Case:**  User needs to be able to select a field of input to review.  This field request is then passed through the query which then returns the lists of inputs by the user for review.  Basically, a dynamic Select Statement in SQL where the FROM column is a variable defined by the user.

**Method:** Using C# and Linq I've written the following Linq Query to return the data, however, I'm not able to swap the actual field name in the query with a variable that has been set by the user.

**Research:** I've reviewed a dozen or so similar questions and articles and they all seem far more complicated than what I'm trying to accomplish and they don't seem to answer the question I have fully; that or I'm just not understanding what the solution actually is.  I've tried playing around with Dynamic Linq without much luck and using Expression Trees seems far more complicated that what I'm hoping is actually necessary.

**Explicitly Defined Field Select:**

```
                    var Values = conn.Table<DataTable>()
                                      .Where(t => t.User_ID == ID)
                                      .Select(t => FieldName).Distinct().ToList();
```

**Variable Field Select**

```
                   //allowing the user to set the value
                   string UserSelectedField = y_List[0].ToString(); 
                   var Values = conn.Table<DataTable>()
                                    .Where(t => t.User_ID == ID)
                                    .Select(t => @UserSelectedField).Distinct().ToList();
```

In the first query I get the results I'm looking for, but it is only able to return the values from the field typed in the code.

The Second returns the object name like {FieldName = FieldName}.

I've also tried just concatenating this in the query, but that didn't work.  Figured it wouldn't, but was worth a shot.

Comment: If you need quick and simple - you can use library like this: https://dynamic-linq.net/

Comment: You should be able to use [LINQKit](https://github.com/scottksmith95/LINQKit) and create string queries, but there are some large limitations - e.g. you wouldn't know the static type of `Values` at compile time so you can't reference any fields directly.

Comment: @Evk all of their readme data goes to a non-existent page and their samples do not work for me for some reason.  I tried that previously.  I'm sure I'm doing something wrong or something, but it doesn't work and there isn't any instructions that I could find that were helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to write own extension, limitation here that you have to know type of the field:

```
public static class MyExtensions
{
    public class DynamicHelper<T>
    {
        private IQueryable<T> _query;

        internal DynamicHelper(IQueryable<T> query)
        {
            _query = query;
        }

        public IQueryable<TResult> SelectByFieldName<TResult>(string fieldName)
        {
            return MyExtensions.SelectByFieldName<T, TResult>(_query, fieldName);
        }
    }

    public static DynamicHelper<T> Dynamic<T>(this IQueryable<T> query)
    {
        return new DynamicHelper<T>(query);
    }

    private static IQueryable<TResult> SelectByFieldName<T, TResult>(IQueryable<T> query, string fieldName)
    {
        var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "e");
        Expression body = Expression.PropertyOrField(param, fieldName);
        if (body.Type != typeof(TResult))
            body = Expression.Convert(body, typeof(TResult));
        var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, TResult>>(body, param);
        return query.Select(lambda);
    }
}
```

And usage

```
string UserSelectedField = y_List[0].ToString(); 
var Values = conn.Table<DataTable>()
   .Where(t => t.User_ID == ID)
   .Dynamic().SelectByFieldName<string>(UserSelectedField)
   .Distinct()
   .ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks @Svyatoslav Danyliv.  However, when I try your code I'm getting errors on the '<T>' for the second instance of 'DynamicHelper<T>' _(CS0246 namespace error)._  on the 'return new DynamicHelper<T>' I get _CS0122 (protection level error)_ and on 'Expression.Convert(body, typeof(TResult))' I get a _CS0029 error on Unary to MemberExpression implicit conversion._

Comment: Sorry about that, updated answer. Just written in browser without compiling.

Comment: is the .Dynamic() a property or method that is built into a namespace or is it a call to the DynamicHelper<T> Dynamic<T> method?  For some reason, I'm getting a compiler error saying that my table does not contain a definition for Dynamic() or an accessible extension that takes a TableQuery<DataTable> as the first argument cannot be found.  Does this extension need to go into the class with the Table?  Or should it go into its own class?

Comment: TableQuery<DataTable>?? What is it? It is IQueryable?

Comment: DataTable is the table being queried and the error occurs in the "and usage" part of the above at .Dynamic().  I'm assuming that the TableQuery<DataTable> is referring to the extension method "Dynamic" in the "MyExtensions" class, since it takes an argument of 'this IQueryable<T> query' I'm assuming that is the query being referred to.

Comment: Side note, I created a new class for the first section of the code called "My Extensions" which is separate from the implementation of the table or the procedure.  I call the "And usage" part of the above solution in the procedure's class.  Is this correct?

Comment: Your class should be `public static` only then extensions will work.

Comment: My Extensions is, does the Class it is being called from need to be public static also?  Or does all of it need to be inside the same class?

Comment: I still don't understand problems that you have faced. I have tested this extension and it works. Extension methods should be in `public static class` and this class should be not nested in any other class.

Comment: lol....yeah, I'm clearly missing something here.  So, I have 3 classes.  1 is the public static class "My Extensions" where I pasted your code.  2 is the table structure class called "DataTable" which is the class called when we query the SQLite database in the background.  3 is the Page class that contains the instructions for the page where I pasted your second lines of code under "And usage".  I am assuming this is the correct structure.

Comment: So, if I'm reading this correctly, we're calling Dynamic() which has an input parameter of a query and in this case we are using the public version of .SelectByFieldName() query whose input is the field name while DynamicHelper is called with the query parameter which sets the _query value.  This _query value is then applied to the public SelectByFieldName which takes as its first argument the _query and the second argument the field name.  This then calls the private SelectByFieldName method which actually runs the query.

Comment: Correct, DynamicHelper class created to simplify calls. Without that you should specify all generic type arguments explicitly - which for anonymous cases is a problem,

Comment: When you ask is TableQuery<DataTable> an IQueryable, it is a SQLite database table.  It is a public class called DataTable which serves as the framework to create the table for SQLite and there is a public class of the same name that is used to reference the table during the queries.  I normally query the database something like the following:                    List<string> x_List = conn.Table<DataTable>().Where(t => t.User_ID == ID).Select(t => t._Index).Distinct().ToList();  Not sure if that is an iQueryable.  I'm new to the iQueryable concept and it's kicking my butt apparently.

Comment: Going through and rekeying it, it looks like it doesn't find the Extension for some reason.  Would there be a namespace or something I'd need to key in?  It already has the namespace for the mod so it has access to the .cs file where it is stored.  Just not sure if there is something else.

Comment: Add `using` to namespace which contains this extension class. It's obvious.

Comment: Yeah, I already had that.  The problem was that the query wasn't an IQueryable.  So, I added '.AsQueryable' after the Where Clause and that fixed the problem.  But when it runs I get a "No coercion operator is defined between types System.String and System.DateTime" (Datetime just happens to be the first user defined field in the test I'm running, it could be any type).

Comment: re-read first sentence of my answer. Do SelectByFieldName<object>

Comment: Right.  I've been doing a lot of reading on the subject and forgot your comment there.  Perfect!  Works now.  Thanks for putting up with my ignorance on this one.