# Linq Select Column by string Column name without reflection or library

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I am trying

```cs
_context.Entity
    .Include(x => x.Addresses)
    .Select(/*I want to pass string column name to get it instead of (x => x.Column)*/);
```

any recommendations?

I have tried the Dynamic.Linq library and reflection but I am trying to find something with better performance..

Comment: It is easy, but which result type do you expect? `IQueryable<object>`? Also note that with `Select`, `Include` is unnecessary.

Comment: Why the include if you only want to read a single property? Have you considered rawsql? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/sql-queries#querying-scalar-non-entity-types

Comment: I want the result type to be of property type, IQueryable<object> should work as well. thanks for the note @SvyatoslavDanyliv!

Comment: thanks @RandRandom but I am trying to do something more dynamic, this is just a simple question that can help.

Comment: Can you check this my answer with [SelectByFieldName](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64529711/10646316) If is is not suitable, I can correct it.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv It is working perfectly thanks! but from your point of view, there is a way to make it more dynamic. instead of passing the type of the property directly, can we pass string class name or an instance of it, is it feasible? :') because i am using it in a generic controller

Comment: Provide your question with method signature. I will post answer exactly for your needs.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv thanks a lot brother. I fixed it, just removed TResult and returned an object +  Expression.Convert(body, type); brought the type from Type.GetType("ModelName"). Thanks a lot!